# symfony2 routing with default placeholder

Tags: php, symfony, routes, placeholder

app/config/routing_dev.yml:

```
people:
    resource: "@myPeopleBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /people
```

myPeopleBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml:

```
people_homepage:
    pattern:  /{name}
    defaults: { _controller: myPeopleBundle:Default:index, name: Foo }

people_homepage2:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: myPeopleBundle:Default:index, name: Bar }
```

myPeopleBundle:Controller:DefaultController.php:

```
...
public function indexAction($name) {
    return $this->render('myPeopleBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
}
...
```

myPeopleBundle:Default:index.html.twig:

```
Hello {{ name }}!
```

---

`web/app_dev.php/people ->` Hello Foo!
`web/app_dev.php/people/ ->` Hello Bar!

Why is it different? The `people_homepage` route why not match the second (`web/app_dev.php/people/`) url?

But if I set the `prefix` to `/` I get the same output:
`web/app_dev.php ->` Hello Foo!
`web/app_dev.php/ ->` Hello Foo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look `appdevUrlMatcher.php` you will see something like this:

```
    // people_homepage
    if (preg_match('#^/people(?:/(?P<name>[^/]++))?$#s', $pathinfo, $matches)) {
        return $this->mergeDefaults(array_replace($matches, array('_route' => 'people_homepage')), array (  '_controller' => 'Acme\\DemoBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::indexAction',  'name' => 'Foo',));
    }

    // people_homepage2
    if (rtrim($pathinfo, '/') === '/people') {
        if (substr($pathinfo, -1) !== '/') {
            return $this->redirect($pathinfo.'/', 'people_homepage2');
        }

        return array (  '_controller' => 'Acme\\DemoBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::indexAction',  'name' => 'Bar',  '_route' => 'people_homepage2',);
    }
```

You can see that  that the route `/people/` can not have no match with `people_homepage`, but it will be with `/people` or `/people/test`

For what you are doing would make more sense if you change the order of the routes

```
people_homepage2:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: myPeopleBundle:Default:index, name: Bar }

people_homepage:
    pattern:  /{name}
    defaults: { _controller: myPeopleBundle:Default:index, name: Foo }
```

With this configuration you will have:

`/people` == `/people/` ---> `people_homepage2`

`/people/test` ---> `people_homepage`